# AWS Lambas - More efficient to return the data from the Lambda or Reference to S3 object?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So I have a lambda building a PDF file. It's storing the data in S3 for caching purposes. If the file isn't too large to be returned as a byte array from the lambda execution, should it be returned that way, or is it more efficient to return a reference to the s3 object and have it downloaded on the other end?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use lambda to generate a presigned URL -> return url to user -> user download file from the url.

Comment: can't, it has to be encrypted at rest.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-s3-part-3/